# MATLAB - add a fitted distribution curve to a histogram

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I'd like to fit a distribution curve to my data, and plot it on top of a histogram of the data.

I can't find how to do it (I'm a MATLAB beginner).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[Distribution Fitting (C) Mathworks http://www.mathworks.com/products/demos/shipping/stats/cfitdfitdemo_06.png](http://www.mathworks.com/products/demos/shipping/stats/cfitdfitdemo_06.png)

If so, check the Mathworks page on [Curve Fitting and Distribution Fitting](http://www.mathworks.com/products/statistics/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/stats/cfitdfitdemo.html)

Comment: Thanx a lot, i finally get my graph!

Answer (score 8):

What you want is the "hold" command.  It keeps the current plot/axes in place and enables you to put a new plot on top of another one. E.g.:

```
hist(somedata);
hold;
plot(someotherdata);
```

[see here](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hold.html)